# SQL Update statistics causing waiting tasks

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

We had a DBA come in a few months ago and setup maintenance plans on our database. Looking at performance stats we are seeing that the task Update Statistics is running overnight and spilling in to operational hours. the vast majority of time it is working on tblAudit, this is a very large table (60Gb) and we don't need it to be part of the maintenance plan but we cannot see a way to exclude this one table. Please see attached pictures.

[image: maintenance plan]
[image: maintenance plan 2]
[image: Performance stats]

Is there an easy way to exclude this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sorry i should have specified. SQL server 2016 Enterprise. using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio V17.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Short (but hesitant) answer: Yes, you could update that task and remove updating statistics for the big table, I'm including a screen shot - not sure why your screen shot does not seem to have anything in the "Object" drop down. I would not recommend this as your solution though and would not do this on any server, personally.

[image]

**If** you do implement certain objects to update and exclude objects, I believe it will make your life even worse because your statistics won't be run on any new objects added to the database - meaning if any new objects are added they would not be covered in this task **AND** the table being excluded from any update statistics maintenance could lead to a potentially huge performance hit on the big table.

Does that large table get **any** transactions (**updates/inserts/deletes)** at all or is it **fully static** (never changes)? Because if it does have any changes daily, weekly or monthly, it most likely will need updated statistics. There is an internal threshold that gets triggered for automated updating of statistics (if your database is configured with Auto Update and Auto Create), and the more rows/more data you have in a table the more updates to the data are needed to trigger an automated statistic update. What that means is the table could have potentially bad performance, especially over time if you leave it out of any mainteance task for stats updating.

I would suggest you look into implementing Ola Hallengren's maintenance plans instead of what the contract DBA created - which is merely out of the box point and click maintenance plan in your screen shot. It is usually unnecessary to do full scans on all statistics (url: https://ola.hallengren.com/).

If nothing else, perhaps JUST the statistics maintenance pieces of the scripts shared on Ola's site. I've used a modified version of the scripts to do our statistics maintenance using modified guidelines for our workload. A competent DBA would understand your workload, how often the data changes and if fullscan is needed, and when. Perhaps if you have a good maintenance window on the weekend, kick off a update statistics for that large table on the weekend, but leave a nightly script for all other tables.